# SQL Server order desc and also show 6/6

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a 3 columns in a table named col1, col2, col3 containing integer values. there are 4000 + rows. there is three parameter @first, @second , @third. I want to get rows who has match according to this parameter. The query is giving results but it is not giving me 3/3 or if there is no match it is not showing and also I want to make it descending order.
My output should be like this

```
table :
col1  col2 col3
 3      4    5
 1      2    2
 7      7    9
 3      2    3
 1      8    9
 1      2    3
first = 1 second = 2 and third = 3 

    3 / 3    1 ( as sixth row contains 1, 2, 3)
    2 / 3    2  ( as second row and fourth row )
    1 / 3    1   (fifth row)
    0 / 3    2   (ist , third )

     (
       SELECT  count (CASE WHEN col1 = @First THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN col2= @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN col3 = @third THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    )AS "NUM_OF_MATCHES" ,
                CAST( CASE WHEN col1 = @First THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  +
                CASE WHEN col2= @sec/ond THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  +
                CASE WHEN col3 = @third THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/ 3'
            AS "match"
    FrOM dbo.FormsDataRowFormat a
    where ( SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = @First THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col2= @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN col3 = @third THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "NUM_OF_MATCHES"  )  >= 1

    group by  ( CASE WHEN col1 = @First THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN col2 = @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
      CASE WHEN col3 = @third THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )        
        )
```

Comment: this doesn't help,please update your question with your expected result and actual result.please look this link (https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)  to know,how to frame a good question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
'0/3' AS Matches, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = @first  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col2 = @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col3 = @third  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches
FROM FormsDataRowFormat
UNION
SELECT '1/3' AS Matches,
SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = @first  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col2 = @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col3 = @third  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches
FROM FormsDataRowFormat
UNION
SELECT '2/3' AS Matches,
SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = @first  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col2 = @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col3 = @third  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches
FROM FormsDataRowFormat
UNION
SELECT '3/3' AS Matches,
SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = @first  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col2 = @second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
               CASE WHEN col3 = @third  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches
FROM FormsDataRowFormat
```

For input data:

```
/--------------------\
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|------+------+------|
|   8  |   7  |   1  |
|   5  |   7  |   1  |
|   4  |   4  |   4  |
|   4  |   5  |   2  |
|   4  |   6  |   2  |
|   2  |   2  |   3  |
|   5  |   2  |   1  |
|   2  |   7  |   7  |
|   2  |   1  |   3  |
|   1  |   2  |   3  |
\--------------------/
```

with:

```
@first = 1
@second = 2
@third = 3
```

gives output:

```
/----------------------\
| Matches | NumMatches |    
|---------+------------|
|   0/3   |      6     |
|   1/3   |      2     |
|   2/3   |      1     |
|   3/3   |      1     |
\----------------------/
```

**Edit - Dynamic SQL solution**:

Following your comment clarifying that the number of columns is dynamic (between 3 and 6 inclusive), below is a dynamic SQL solution which will handle any such number of columns.

Note however that dynamic SQL is probably not the best solution to this problem, especially if it's something which will be repeated many times and/or runs on very large datasets. However, it's the only way I know to achieve this, so I wanted to include it (and would be very happy to see better solutions from other users!).

```
DECLARE @numColumns INT
SELECT @numColumns = COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects o JOIN syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id WHERE o.name = 'FormsDataRowFormat'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql =
'SELECT ' +
'''0/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
               ') = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' +
'UNION ' +
'SELECT ''1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
               ') = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' +
'UNION ' +
'SELECT ''2/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
               ') = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' +
'UNION ' +
'SELECT ''3/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
               'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
               ') = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' +
CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN 
    'UNION ' +
    'SELECT ''4/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
    'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                   ') = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN 
    'UNION ' +
    'SELECT ''5/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
    'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                   ') = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN @numColumns = 6 THEN 
    'UNION ' +
    'SELECT ''6/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@numColumns) + ''' AS Matches, ' +
    'SUM(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN col1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@first) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col2 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@second) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ' +
                   'CASE WHEN col3 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@third) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 4 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col4 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fourth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns >= 5 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col5 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fifth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @numColumns  = 6 THEN ' + CASE WHEN col6 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sixth) + '  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' ELSE '' END +
                   ') = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumMatches ' +
'FROM FormsDataRowFormat' ELSE '' END 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: if there are 6 column i have repeat this query six time .

Comment: So do you have 3 columns (as per your question), or 6? Are you saying the number of columns is variable? You should state this in your question if so. The solution I give above can easily be rewritten for any static number of columns if you want. If your number of columns is variable, we'll have to take a slightly more sophisticated approach.

Comment: thanks for kind reply. Currently there are 3 column the calomn may waries maximum 6

Comment: Ok, so there will be a variable number of columns between 3 and 6 in total? If so, you should really add this to your question to avoid getting unhelpful answers.

Comment: thanks for kind reply. Currently there are 3 column the columns may varies maximum 6

Second your answer is giving result horizontal form i want result in vertical form  like this 

3/3  1
2/3  1
1/3  2
0/3   6

Comment: Add this new requirement to the question to make your needs clear to others who might want to answer. It's trivial to present the results as a number of rows rather than a number of columns, I will update the answer now.

Comment: I've also added a dynamic SQL solution to handle any number of columns from 3-6, although I would hope someone else will be able to show you a better way to do this (ideally something that could be scaled to n-columns without writing additional code).

Comment: thanks for you reply. But there should be any other solution for this rather then repeating same query again and again.

Comment: @Martin I'm sure there is, but does this solution not solve your problem? What goes wrong when you run this on your data?